# My xpath/php output needs to show the tags

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to get an xpath xpression that will remove my outer tag, but it's removing that, plus the inner tag and printing the element data.  How do I get it to print my prompt tags also?

**My php looks like this:**

```
<?php
#get file
$xml = simplexml_load_file('content.xml') or die ("Unable to load XML string!");

#loop through results
foreach ( $xml->xpath('//prompt') as $voiceQ) {
  echo "<h2>Thank you for visiting our site2</h2>";
  print $voiceQ;
} //for
?>
```

**My content.xml looks like this**
(I'm writing to this file and it's losing some formatting.  I don't think this is the problem):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <prompt>
        Welcome to Group Finder, Mary Lamb . We see that
        you  like the group:   JackJohnson
    </prompt>
</result>
```

**My output looks like this:**
Welcome to Group Finder, Mary Lamb . We see that you like the group: JackJohnson

**But I want it to look like this:**
(just remove result tags):

```
<prompt>Welcome to Group Finder, Mary Lamb . We see that you  like the group: JackJohnson</prompt>
```

Comment: I figured out that I can write output to screen with prompt tags with 
    print $voiceQ->asXML();

But when I try to write it to my file, it loses the prompt tags again.  How do I keep my prompt tags when I write to file?

Comment: Oh.  I figured it out.  I needed to write it to file with asXML()

Comment: If you've figured it out, you should post the answer using the Answer box (you're allowed to answer your own questions) and then mark that as your chosen answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [asXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-asXML.php) method on SimpleXMLElement:

```
<?php
$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><result>
<prompt>Welcome to Group Finder, Mary Lamb . We see that you  like the group:   JackJohnson</prompt></result>';

#get file
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

#loop through results
foreach ( $xml->xpath('//prompt') as $voiceQ) {
  echo "<h2>Thank you for visiting our site2</h2>";
  print $voiceQ->asXML();
} //for
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if result is within prompt just loop a little bit more :)

```
  <php?
    #get file
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('content.xml') or die ("Unable to load XML string!");

    #loop through results
    foreach ( $xml->xpath('//prompt') as $voiceQ) {
      foreach($voiceQ AS $inVoice)
        {
           echo "<h2>Thank you for visiting our site2</h2>";
           print $inVoice;
         }
    } //for
    ?>
```